# Datastax Gremlin Tool: Host not responding

Tags: azure, datastax-enterprise, gremlin, gremlin-server, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am trying to deploy a Datastax Enterprise cluster through Azure in order to utilize the graph engine released with DSE 5.0.

Unfortunately, the Azure DSE Deployment deploys DSE 4.8, which does not support gremlin or the new DSE Graph engine. So, I have tried following the [installation guide](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/install/installUnattendedDse.html) in order to upgrade the nodes on the cluster to version 5.0.

After doing so, I can launch the gremlin console with:

```
$: dse gremlin-console
```

Following the [Datastax Graph Tutorial](https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds330-datastax-enterprise-graph/managing-graphs), I then try to create a graph by calling `system.graph("test").create()`, which gives me the following error:

```
Host did not respond in a timely fashion - check the server status and submit again.
```

I'm not sure whether I screwed up some configurations when upgrading from DSE 4.8 to 5.0, or whether I simply have to configure some gremlin configurations to get this working. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does cqlsh work? I'm guessing this is an RPC address issue but I'm not sure

Comment: I was actually able to fix this by simply running `:remote config alias reset`

Comment: Oh yeah. I thought you did that since you pointed to that page in the docks. I had hit the same problem my first time